# jQuery slideToggle not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery to slide out a div containing text on click of a div, but it's not working in Internet Explorer 8, while appearing fine in Firefox and Chrome. It's pretty basic, so I've no idea what I'm missing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#help").click(function(){
        $('.flyout').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

There's a jsFiddle of the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/tetsujin1979/yj5h3van/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a IE8 bug,

just apply the following css to the block(s) element(s) with the margin in conflict (which disappears)

```
overflow : hidden
```

I don't know if this solution could be automated by jQuery

Comment: sorry, still not working, I've added the "overflow: hidden" style change to the parent "help" div and the "floyout" div, but still no luck.